# Copy lines containing a specific text from one file to another file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I want to copy over all lines in a file (`file1.txt`) containing `Cmd:[41]` over to another file (`file2.txt`)

```
awk '/Cmd:[41]/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

This command doesn't seem to work. The `file2.txt` is of size 0. However there are lines in `file1.txt` that **contains** `Cmd:[41]`

Is there some specific `awk` escape character that I should be using. The problem is with `[41]` part. The other part of the search string seems to work fine.

Comment: see also: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue? If it is the case could you put it as correct answer? Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your command in the following way and it will work:

```
awk '/Cmd:\[41\]/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

**Explanations:**

`'/Cmd:[41]/'` will match lines that contain: `Cmd:4` or `Cmd:1` but will not match lines that contain literally `Cmd:[41]` as `[...]` are used in regex to define a **character range**, or a **list of characters** that can be matched therefore you need to escape them by adding a `\` before them.